# Create a loop in a java program

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program in which the user will first be shown a menu from which they can select a number of options. I have tried to create a code which, once an option has been selected will return the user to the menu. However, the program simply ends rather than looping the user back to the menu. What do I need to add to the code so that once the selection methods have been run through it will return the user to the selection menu?

Here's an excerpt showing the relevant part of the program:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int selection = 0;


    while (x == 0) {
        System.out.println("Please make a selection");
        System.out.println("[1] Make a new booking");
        System.out.println("[2] View films");
        System.out.println("[3] View Screens");
        System.out.println("[4] View Customers");
        System.out.println("[5] View showing information");
        System.out.println("[6] View booking information");
        System.out.println("[7] Exit");

        while (selection == 0) {
            System.out.println("Selection: ");
            try {
                selection = scanner.nextInt();

            } catch (InputMismatchException nfe) {
                System.out.println("Input must be a number");
                selection = 0;
                scanner = null;
                scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            }
        }
        switch (selection) {

            case 1:

                System.out.println("All available showings:");
                x = 1;

                for (Showing aShowing : showingList) {
                    System.out.println(aShowing.toString());
                }

                System.out.println("Enter the showing number: ");
                int show = scanner.nextInt();

                Showing userChoice = showingList.get(show - 1);

                System.out.println("Enter the number of tickets: ");

                int tickets = scanner.nextInt();


                Booking booking1 = new Booking(customerA, userChoice, tickets);

                System.out.println(booking1);


                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("Current films being shown:");
                x = 1;
                System.out.println("Film one: " + filmA.getTitle()
                        + ".\nLength: " + filmA.getDuration() + " minutes."
                        + "\nAge Rating: " + filmA.getAgeRating()
                        + ".\nDescription: " + filmA.getDescription() + ".");
                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println("Screen information:");
                x = 1;
                System.out.println("Screen id:" + screenA.getId()
                        + ".\nSeats a maximum of " + screenA.getCapacity() + " people.");
                break;
```

Comment: Because you set x to 1, and your loop is checking for x == 0.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest changing your inner while condition to be while(sel<=0 || sel > 7). You want to limit to valid values, and 12 isn't one :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what `while(x==0)` is doing there.

What I have understood from your requirement is, you want to offer user a menu with options and user needs to enter his choice and a operation will be performed according to that and then again ask for another input from user.

If this is the case, then try writing your logic the following way,

```
do{
    System.out.println("Please make a selection");
    System.out.println("[1] Make a new booking");
    System.out.println("[2] View films");
    System.out.println("[3] View Screens");
    System.out.println("[4] View Customers");
    System.out.println("[5] View showing information");
    System.out.println("[6] View booking information");
    System.out.println("[7] Exit");

    selection = scanner.nextInt();

    switch(selection){

        case 1:
           ...
        //so on

        case 7:
           //do nothing
           break;
        default:
           System.out.println("Wrong number entered");

    }



}while(selection!=7);
```